# Angular FormGroup patchValue works but changes are not shown

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So I have this piece of code which subscribes to event which emits user data. This user data I want to pre-populate my Edit Form, but it is not working properly.

```
export class EditUserComponent implements OnInit{
    
    constructor (private userService: UserService,
        private router: Router,
        private alertService: AlertService,
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    }
    
    userModel: IEditUserModel;
    editUserForm:FormGroup;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.editUserForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            userName: ['123'],
            firstname: ['123'],
            lastname: ['123'],
            email: ['123']
        })

        this.userService.getEditUserInfoEvent().subscribe({
            next: (editUserInfo)=> 
            {
                this.userModel = editUserInfo,
                this.setEditFormEventValues(this.userModel)
                console.log(this.userModel)
            }
        })
    }

    private setEditFormEventValues(userModel: IEditUserModel) {
      this.editUserForm.patchValue({
        userName: userModel.userName,
        firstname: userModel.firstname,
        lastname: userModel.lastname,
        email: userModel.email
      })
    }
```

The "123" values are for testing purposes. The event containing the user information is received during OnInit. Then, when I put breakpoint on the last patchValue method bracket here is the information about the form:
[image]
From here we can see that the values are somehow updated - Foncho123 is my new username value from the event subscribtion. But the actual visual form input fields are not changed, at all. Is there anything that I am missing?
Here is a small piece of my HTML view, which is identical for all input fields.

```
<form [formGroup]="editUserForm">
    <label for="uname">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="uname" name="username" formControlName="userName">
```

Comment: Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: Not really. Also, my IEditUserModel is an interface. Is that a problem?

Comment: Can you check whether your component is set on OnPush strategy or not?

Comment: it's problem with you use [ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush](https://angular.io/guide/change-detection-skipping-subtrees). BTW, as your userModel has the same properties that the name of the FormControls, you can use simply: `this.editUserForm.patchValue(userModel)`

Comment: Not sure about this DetectionStrategy. Did not use it at all. I will check how to implement it.

Comment: No. My component did not have this OnPush strategy.

Comment: The interesting part is that from the tutorial I am watching such thing is not used.

Answer (score 1):

Use the change detection trigger

```js
export class EditUserComponent implements OnInit{
    
    constructor (private userService: UserService,
        private router: Router,
        private alertService: AlertService,
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder
        private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    }
    
    userModel: IEditUserModel;
    editUserForm:FormGroup;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.editUserForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            userName: ['123'],
            firstname: ['123'],
            lastname: ['123'],
            email: ['123']
        })

        this.userService.getEditUserInfoEvent().subscribe({
            next: (editUserInfo)=> 
            {
                this.userModel = editUserInfo,
                this.setEditFormEventValues(this.userModel)
                console.log(this.userModel)
                this.cdRef.detectChanges();
            }
        })
    }

    private setEditFormEventValues(userModel: IEditUserModel) {
      this.editUserForm.patchValue({
        userName: userModel.userName,
        firstname: userModel.firstname,
        lastname: userModel.lastname,
        email: userModel.email
      })
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but nothing happened.

Comment: Then make sure your code is ran correctly.

Comment: What does that mean? Clearly there is a problem, but cannot figure it out.

Comment: Use `console.log` to see if all logs are running (this way you can see if the code is being ran)